# POST base64 encoded textarea data from file with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I try to POST some data to a PHP script with VBScript, but something I do wrong...

```
Dim objStream
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
objStream.Open()
objStream.LoadFromFile("base64.txt")
objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHTTP.open "POST", "http://mysite.com/data.php", False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send "data=" + objDocElem.text
'MsgBox objHTTP.responseText
Set objHTTP = Nothing
Set objStream = Nothing
```

> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\data\test.vbe(3, 1)
>   ADODB.Stream : Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable
>   range, or are in confli ct with one another.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

```
Dim TextArea
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TextFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("base64.txt", 1)
TextArea = ""
Do Until TextFile.AtEndOfStream
    TextArea = TextArea & TextFile.ReadLine & vbNewLine
Loop
TextFile.Close

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHTTP.open "POST", "http://mysite.com/data.php", False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send "data=" + TextArea
Set oFSO = Nothing
Set TextFile = Nothing
Set objHTTP = Nothing
```